# text in middle of two horizontal rules

Tags: minipage

here is a code to produce an item list between two horizontal rules. To make the text (itemize or just plain text) setting the minipage with [c] option should be fine but the content is not perfectly in the middle of the two rules. the gap between a rule and the text should be like a top and bottom margin of about 1.5 times the \baselineskip or \itemsep.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[verbose,vmargin=20mm,hmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontsize,fix-cm,enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=$\bullet$}

\changefontsize{24}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[skip=11pt plus1pt, indent=0pt]{parskip}

\begin{document}
\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
\begin{minipage}[t][.2\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item ...walking ...
    \item ...jogging ...
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify at leisure the vertical spacings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{ruled}
  {%
   \par
   \addvspace{2\topsep}
   \noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
   \hrule height 2pt
   \vspace{\topsep}
  }
  {%
   \par\nointerlineskip
   \vspace{\topsep}
   \hrule height 0pt depth 2pt 
   \end{minipage}
   \par
   \addvspace{2\topsep}
  }

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{ruled}
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
    \item ...walking ...
    \item ...jogging ...
\end{itemize}
\end{ruled}

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\begin{ruled}
\lipsum[3][1-4]
\end{ruled}

\lipsum[4][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also want to check `tcolorbox`.

Comment: i replaced \topsep by \baselineskip in the environment definition and it's looking fine. \topsep is equal to 0pt in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The first `\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}` takes the whole line, therefore LaTeX continues in the next line. This is what `minipage` refers to in order align its box.

The option `[t]` instructs `minipage` to use a top alignment to a baseline of its surrounding content (here the empty line). Since you added the third option `[c]`, LaTeX actually refers to edges of the box of the minipage (by default it uses baselines of the inner text). Ultimately, the box is placed so that its top edge is aligned with a baseline of the empty line leaving the extra gap above. The content inside the `minipage` is actually centred.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[verbose,vmargin=20mm,hmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontsize,fix-cm,enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=$\bullet$}

\changefontsize{16}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[skip=11pt plus1pt, indent=0pt]{parskip}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][.2\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
  \item ...walking ...
  \item ...jogging ...
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}
\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}

\bigskip

X
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][.2\textheight][c]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
  \item ...walking ...
  \item ...jogging ...
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}
X
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[b][.2\textheight][c]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
  \item ...walking ...
  \item ...jogging ...
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice explanation. Do you have a solution?

Comment: You have been given solutions from experts and I can't think of another alternative, so I'd leave my answer as is. I would, however, suggest to have a look at [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            margin=20mm,
            showframe
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontsize,fix-cm}
\changefontsize{24}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage[skip=11pt plus1pt, indent=0pt]{parskip}


\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitem,1]{
    label=\textbullet,
    before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
    after =\end{minipage}
                    }
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hlines  = 2pt,
             colspec = {@{} X[j] @{}},
              rowsep  = 11pt}
\lipsum[66]
\end{tblr}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{tblr}{hlines  = 2pt,
             colspec = {@{} X[j] @{}},
             measure = vbox,
             rowsep  = 11pt}
\begin{tabitem}
    \item ...walking ...
    \item ...jogging ...
\end{tabitem}
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(gray lines inf0dicate page layout)